# How to maximize efficiency in this complex data transfer scenario

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, performance, database

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, as it is solely based on theory, however I think this fits best in this stackexchange compared to the rest.

I have 500,000 taxis with Android 4 computers inside them. Everyday, after one person or party makes a trip, the computer sends the information about the trip to the Node.js server. There are roughly 35 trips a day, so that means 500,000 taxis * 35 trips = 17,500,000 reports sent a day to the Node.js server. Also, each report has roughly 4000 characters in it, sized around 5KB.

The report that the taxi computers send to the node.js server is just an http post. Node.js will then send back a confirmation to the taxi. If the taxi does not receive the confirmation for report A in an allotted amount of time, it will resend report A.

The node.js server simply receives the report. Sends the confirmation back to the taxi. And then sends the full report to the MongoDB.

One potential problem : Taxi 1 sends report A to node.js. Node.js does not respond within the allotted time, so Taxi 1 resends report A to node.js. Node.js eventually processes everything and sends report A twice to MongoDB.

Thus MongoDB is in charge of checking whether or not it received multiple of the same reports. Then MongoDB inserts the data.

I actually have a couple of questions. Is this too much for NodeJS to handle (I don't think so, but it could be a problem)? Is this too much for MongoDB to handle? I feel like checking for duplicate reports may severely hinder the performance.

How can I make this whole system more efficient? What should I alter or add?

Comment: I would give your reports a hash ( maybe from a timestamp of the trip and the taxi id), index them and cache them a certain amount of time in your node.js Server. If you recieve a report, just check the last recent hashes, and don't process any further if you have this hash already

Comment: Instead of notifying server of each trip, can you send a group of trip's data to server? Like after every 7 trips, you will send data to server. This way, number of request/response from each taxi will be reduced.

Comment: Agree with RafaelT. It would be better to generate hash, then send report. What bothers me though that what is the max concurrent taxi requests at a time ? Distributing 17,500,000 requests evenly through the day is pointless. There will be a peak time for your 500,000 taxis. It is important to know that number.

Comment: @Shrikant Yes that is certainly possible, as the current system sends a log file at the end of every day now. But the "real-time" aspect seems to have some sort of glow to it (atleast in the company's eyes).

Answer (score 1):

First potential problem is easy to overcome. Calculate a hash of the trip and store them in mongo. Put the key on that field and then compare every next document if the same hash exists. This way checking for duplicate will be extremely easy and really fast. Keep in mind that this document should not have something like time of sending in it.

Second problem: 17,500,000/day is 196/second nontheless sound scary but in reality it is not so much for decent server and for sure is not a problem for Mongodb.

It is hard to tell how to make it more efficient and I highly doubt you should think about it now. Give it a try, do something, check what is not working efficiently and come back with specific questions.

P.S. not to answer all this in the comments. You have to understand that the question is extremely vague. No one knows what do you mean by trip document and how big is it. It can be 1kb, It may be 10Mb, it can be 100Mb (which is bigger then 16 Mb mongodb limit). No one knows. When I told that 196 documents/sec is not a problem, I did not said that exactly this amount of documents is the maximum cap, so even if it will be 2, 3 times more it is still sounds feasible.

**You have to try it yourself**. Take avarage amazon instance and see how many YOUR documents (create documents which are close to your size and structure) it can save per second. If it can not handle it, try to see how much it can, or can amazon big instance handle it.

I gave you a rough estimate that this is possible, and I have no idea that you want to "include admins using MongoDB, to update, select,". Have you told this in your question?

Comment: In regards your Second problem: 17,500,000/day translates to a lot more than 196/second. During off peak hours, taxis will not send that many reports, whereas during rush hour, it is almost impossible to find a taxi. I currently don't have the statistic for on-peak hours, but I can work on getting that. I just edited my original question stating that the average size of a report is 4000 characters, 5KB. Would MongoDB be able to handle the pressure in this updated situation (between checking for duplicate reports as well as inserting)?

Comment: And this doesn't even include admins using MongoDB, to update, select, etc.